# r leaflet icons supported colors

Tags: r, leaflet

I've seen `leaflet` package in R doesn´t support some marker colors provided to `awesomeIcons` function. For example, doesn't accepts "yellow" but accepts "red", "blue" or "green".
Is there any way to know which options are supported?

Answer (score 1):

In the `awesomeIcons` [function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.0.4.1/topics/awesomeIcons) all `markerColor` options are listed:

> Possible values are `"red"`, `"darkred"`, `"lightred"`, `"orange"`, `"beige"`,
> `"green"`, `"darkgreen"`, `"lightgreen"`, `"blue"`, `"darkblue"`, `"lightblue"`,
> `"purple"`, `"darkpurple"`, `"pink"`, `"cadetblue"`, `"white"`, `"gray"`,
> `"lightgray"`, `"black"`